# Cumulative total with restart upon reaching a limit with a condition

Tags: javascript, cumulative-sum

I have an array:

```
arr = [2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 9, 1];
```

All the numbers are below '10'. I want the cumulative total of the numbers. But with two conditions:

1. **upon reaching a total closest to '10' the last number that makes total to be less than or equal to '10' should be replaced with '10'** AND
2. the cumulative total starts from next number.

**So, the output should be:**

```
outputArr = [2, 6, 10, 10, 8, 10, 3, 10, 9, 10];
```

I have this code:

```
arr = [2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 9, 1];
total = 0;
outputArr = [];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (total + arr[i] <= 10) {
    total += arr[i];
    outputArr.push(total);
  } else {
    total = arr[i];
    outputArr.push(total);
  }
}
console.log(outputArr);
```

**This code gives me this output:**

```
outputArr = [2, 6, 9, 7, 8, 10, 3, 7, 9, 10]
```

Here, cumulative total and its restarting upon reaching 10 works fine.
**But the problem as you see is:
before restarting, it can't replace last item with 10.**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the expected output a bit more? I'm not sure I see why the third element should be `10`? What do you mean by a "total closest to 10", closest compared to what exactly? Do you mean a total greater than 10 maybe?

Comment: _"upon reaching a total closest to '10'..."_ - What's the result for `[3, 6, 3]`? `[3, 10, 3]` or `[3, 6, 10]` And `[3, 6, 2]`?

Comment: @Nick Parsons In the original array, 2+4+3=9. Here, adding third element makes total closest to 10 but does not exceed 10. So, I want the 3rd element in the output array to be 10, instead of 9. You can say, 9 rounds off to be 10. Similarly, 4th element 7 rounds off to be 10 because if you add 5th element 8, total exceeds 10. Could I make it clear?

Comment: @Andreas
result for [3,6,3] would be [3,10,3]
result for [3,6,2] would be [3,10,2]
result for [3,6,1] would be [3,6,10]

Comment: Add that explanation in the question, and modify the first condition to be more precise (e.g. The last number that keeps total to be less than or equal to `10` ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could update the output array based on whether the cumulative sum is < 10 or == 10 or > 10

```js
let input = [2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 2, 3, 4, 9, 1],
    output = [],
    cumulative = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  cumulative += input[i];

  if (cumulative < 10) {
    output.push(cumulative)
  } else if (cumulative == 10) {
    output.push(10)
    cumulative = 0
  } else {
    output[i-1] = 10
    cumulative = input[i]
    output.push(cumulative)
  }
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: -given the input: [2,4,3,7], if I want the output to be like this: [2,4,3,1,7,3], what change do I need to do? I have tried changing last else statement to:
`else {
output.push(10 - cumulative[i-1]);
cumulative = input[i];
output.push(cumulative);
}`
But it doesn't work.
I want to add a new element '1' after 3rd element in the output array because now that makes cumulative total to be 10.